# Google hangouts error code "404", "invalid project number"

Tags: chat

Google hangouts chat shows an error code **404**, message **"invalid project number"**. how can we solve this error ?

Comment: Is this a programming related Question? If it is, please edit and add details.

Comment: I think it's related to this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68313592/invalid-project-number-when-using-google-chat-api/69443219#69443219