# Invalid project number when using google chat api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-chat

I'm following [this article](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/service-accounts) to create a message in Google Chat via services account. However when I compile the code, I got the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "googlechat-api.py", line 27, in 
> resp = chat.spaces().messages().create(
> File "C:\Users\tdi5539\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\tdi5539\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 935, in execute
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAcE3QeHo/messages?alt=json returned "Invalid project number.". Details: "Invalid project number.">

Could anyone explain for me what is the problem?

Here is my code by the way:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'credentials.json', scopes)
chat = build('chat', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))
resp = chat.spaces().messages().create(
    parent='spaces/AAAAcE3QeHo', # use your space here
    body={'text': 'Test message'}).execute()
print(resp)
```

Comment: How did you come up with the file `credentials.json`? Can you check whether you can access the corresponding GCP project?

Comment: Hi @Sakshi Gatyan, were you able to find out the root cause. I'm also facing the same issue, which shows "invalid project number" after making the API call

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your Bot, and you can only setup Bots using Google Workspace aka GSuite accounts

In my case I started the project with a @gmail.com account and had to add a user from Google Workspace @mycompany.com to the project and setup the Bot from that account.

Link to setup Google Chat Bots should be something like:
[https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat?authuser=1&project=[your-project]&supportedpurview=project](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat?authuser=1&project=%5Byour-project%5D&supportedpurview=project)

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to use `option.WithQuotaProject` in golang, probably `quota_project_id` in python according to [this page](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/client_options.html)